# How to deploy a juju charm specific to a server in MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, cloud

I need to deploy a charm on one of the free servers available in MAAS. All those servers in ready state will not have an IP/machine number allocated because of which it was not possible for me to deploy.

How do I overcome this problem and deploy the charm accordingly.

In MaaS i can see that there is a option to set a tag for each server. Is it possible to deploy using that tag.??

Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: Did you add the machine to your model? `juju add-machine` adds one of the available MAAS nodes to your model and gives it a machine id starting from 0. Then you can deploy the charm using `juju deploy ~/charm --to 0`

Comment: @user3499430 hey actually its a big charm called openstack-base ..its has so many sub charms under it. In that few services need some specific config(like 2 disks etc.. ) of nodes for it to run. How can i choose it run time.  
your answer is perfectly fine when its for a single charm or when its done manually.  I should have been more specific on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to specific instances in a number of ways using Juju's constraints system. There is general information on using constraints here:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-constraints

and specific instructions in the reference section here for using MAAS tags:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/reference-constraints

If you are deploying a bundle though, rather than an individual charm, you will need to edit the bundle file to make sure that specific applications end up on the right machines:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-bundles#creating-a-bundle